# "In eine Schule überwechseln" oder "an eine Schule überwechseln"?

Tags: grammar, preposition

> Ich will in eine andere Schule überwechseln.
>   Ich will an eine andere Schule überwechseln.

Wie ist es im gegebenen Fall richtiger zu sagen?

Comment: "An". Oder auch "zu".

Comment: "Zu" ist dann "Ich will zu einer anderen Schule überwechseln"

Comment: Und ich würde nur "wechseln" sagen, ohne "über-".

Comment: Ich glaube, diese Frage kann man nicht eindeutig beantworten, schon gar nicht ohne Kenntnis der Region.

Answer (score 5):

Korrekt wäre

> Ich will an eine andere Schule überwechseln

Der Unterschied:

"In der Schule" bezeichnet das Gebäude, "an der Schule" die Institution.

Umgangssprachlich wird aber m.E. eher "in die Schule" verwendet.

[Edit]
Wie @Em1 korrekt anmerkt bezieht sich der obere Teil auf den Kontext der obigen Frage.
"An" kann durchaus auch den räumlichen Kontext haben:

> Ich stehe an der Schule

bezeichnet das Gebäude, nicht die Institution.
Wenn "an" durch "bei", "neben" oder "in der Nähe von" ersetzt werden kann ohne den Inhalt zu ändern, bezeichnet es den Ort.

"In" hingegen bezeichnet stets den Ort.

Comment: Der letzte Satz ist nicht ganz klar."Ich gehe in die Schule" ist zweideutig. Es kann die Instutition meinen oder das Gebäude. "Ich bin in der Schule" ist recht eindeutig, weil in aller Regel das Gebäude gemeint wird (Kontext müsste klar machen, wenn es mal die Instutition ist). "Ich stehe an der Schule" ist eindeutig das Gebäude, insofern bezeichnet dies nicht immer die Instutition. — Auf den konkreten Satz bezogen ist der Kontext natürlich auch entscheidend. Aller Wahrscheinlichkeit nach ist die Institution gemeint, daher ist "Ich will an eine andere/zu einer anderen Schule wechseln" richtig.

Comment: Da hast Du einfach nur recht. Ich werde das nachher ausführlicher formulieren.

Comment: @Em1 Also ich hätte früher "Ich bin in der Schule" auch dann verwendet, wenn ich gemeint hätte, dass ich gerade meine tägliche Schulzeit verbringe. Egal ob ich auf dem Sportplatz, im Gebäude, auf dem Pausenhof oder im Hallenbad gewesen wäre.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar Oh ja, das ist richtig. So gesehen, *kann* der Satz sogar dreideutig sein. Ich bin im Gebäude, ich bin auf dem Schulgelände, oder in sehr seltenen Ausnahmen (meinem Empfinden nach sehr selten, weil meistens mit "gehen" verwendet) ich gehe zur Schule, bin aber gerade nicht dort.

Comment: Willst du noch eine Bedeutung? : "Arbeitest du schon oder gehst du noch in die Schule?" - Hier bezieht sich die Frage nicht auf Ort oder Institution,  auch nicht auf meinen Tagesablauf, sondern auf den Lebensabschnitt.

Comment: @tofro da hätte ich eher gesagt "oder gehst Du noch *zur* Schule"

Comment: "In die Schule" wird oft gleichbedeutend mit "zur Schule" verwendet und kann ohne Kontext nicht eindeutig bestimmt werden. Noch schlimmer: Nicht einmal das Hinzufügen einer zeitlichen Bestimmung macht es eindeutig, vgl. "Ich gehe noch in die Schule" mit "Ich gehe noch kurz in die Schule".
Regional wird auch häufig "auf die Schule" verwendet, z.B. "Ich gehe auf die Goetheschule", "Sie geht aufs Gymnasium".